# How to add image automaticly on excel

Tags: excel, vba, image-processing, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a excel file like below image. In column `C` there are product code & local drive there are images with that product code. Now I want insert image on column `W` automatically for image column. How it's possible?
`(I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2007)`

[image]

Comment: [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can see here an example :
http://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/insert-pictures-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html